# Splitting the table to get more clusterization options - will it help?

Tags: index, index-tuning, clustered-index

Complete theory.

Let's assume we have a table with a few millions rows. The table has clustered index over PK, and it is important for quick fetching of particular rows. However, the table also has a column kind of `CreatedDateTime` (non clustered index), and by reasons of report building over particular time span, obviously, it would be great to cluster it too.

Will it help, if I split the table in two - `TMain` with clustered PK, and `TMainTime`, with `(MainId)` as non clustered PK, and `(CreatedDateTime)` for clustered index? It looks like I can determine the timespan required using `TMainTime`, searching over its clustered datetime, and then, with `MainId` values found, fetch them searching over clustered PK in `TMain` table. Will it ever add something to performance? Or will it eliminate any possible gain by `JOIN` operation over the two tables?

Comment: Hi Welcome to the site, Please add full table definitions, and the queries that give you problems along with execution plans.

Comment: @TomV Well there is no concrete table. I'm just searching if the described approach makes sense. That is, if you want additional clustered index, you just move fields you need to index in another table.

Comment: Is the question about SQL Server or some other DBMS?

Comment: It won't matter that much which way you do it.  Obviously the query which aligns with the clustered index will perform slightly better.  But a non-clustered index on the CreatedDateTime, PrimaryKey will perform mostly the same.  Just decide if it's more important for the reports to go slightly faster or for the picking of one row to go slightly faster.  I would imagine that your createdDateTime field is growing mostly in line with your primary key so the nonclustered index shouldn't defragment very fast.  I would prefer to make the reports work harder for data than my one at a time.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yep mostly about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a theoretical question I'm sure there will be corner cases where that is a good idea but as a general rule I wouldn't go down that path.

You will, as you state, complicate your regular queries by having to join both tables and you will also complicate your inserts/updates.

A well designed, properly normalized, database with proper indexing on a server that has been sized well should perform adequate with a couple of million rows (and a lot more than that).

For reference, the stack exchange network runs on a mainstream RDBMS and uses no special design tricks. You can verify that for yourself by [downloading the database](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).